# How to get exact kml file path?

Tags: leaflet, kml

I tried to show kml file using open layers v3, but I did not get proper path, I tried leaflet to show kml file, I had download the same code of example of leaflet.

```
  const map = new L.Map('map', { center: new L.LatLng(23.8086,78.6188), zoom: 6 });
            const osm = new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');

            map.addLayer(osm);

            // Load kml file
            fetch('../kml/2018.kml')
                .then(res => res.text())
                .then(kmltext => {
                    // Create new kml overlay
                    const parser = new DOMParser();
                    const kml = parser.parseFromString(kmltext, 'text/xml');
                    const track = new L.KML(kml);
                    map.addLayer(track);

                    // Adjust map to show the kml
                    const bounds = track.getBounds();
                    map.fitBounds(bounds);
                });
```

Error: Bounds are not valid.

Comment: TypeError: L.KML is not a constructor

Comment: Have you loaded the KML plugin?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css"
  integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
  crossorigin=""/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"
  integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og=="
  crossorigin=""></script>  this online source i used.

Comment: So you haven't loaded the plugin. Follow the example at https://github.com/windycom/leaflet-kml

Comment: i had used the same code, but i am stuck where to put this files, js files and all are ok but what about asset folder?

Comment: You don't need the `assets` folder

Comment: when i tried to implement in my project it did not work.

Comment: @vyomaes - Did you get it to work?  I'm stuck at the same spot